# Set css Attributes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, css

How do i set the css attributes with jquery in _ViewStart.cshtml?
Because i need to set the css attributes in _Viewstart.cshtml i dont really know how to get the css file to the viewstart. I know how to change the attribute with but i dont know how to get this element from the css. This is how much i have done right now:

```
@using Repository
@using Services
@{
var servicetemp = ServiceFactory.Instance.CreateTemplateService();
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var TemplateIDSession = Session["TemplateID"];

    if (TemplateIDSession != null)
    {
        int tempID = (int)TemplateIDSession;
        var template = servicetemp.GetEntry(tempID);

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("Body").css({ background-color: "#" + "@template.TempBG" }),
            $("Header").css({background-color: "#" + "@template.TempBG" });
        </script> 
    }
}
}
```

--UPDATE--
this is the new javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").css('background-color:', '#' + '@template.TempBG'),
    $("#Layout").css('background-color:', '#' + '@template.TempBG');
</script>
```

But it still doesnt work to replace the value for the css elements, the css file is located in another folder

Comment: Use quotes on the property name `{"background-color":...`. or you'll get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token -`.

Comment: @nnnnnn can i use this code to set the attribute? $("Body").css('background-color', '#' '@template.BGcolor'),

Comment: If you put a `+` in between `'#'` and `'@template.BGcolor'` then yes as far as the JS side goes. (I don't remember how the ASP side works, it's been too long.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Ty, it doesnt work yet becuase the BgColor is null in the debugg which is kind a wierd since it has data in the database, but once i get the correct data it will hopefully work with this code, just not sure if to put the ":", if its 'background-color:' or 'background-color':

Comment: @nnnnnn I think its something wrong with the jquery code, that it doesnt replace the value in the cssfile which is located in another folder, becuase i wrote string test = template.TempBG; and i do get the right data in it

Comment: The colon goes outside the quotes (as per my original comment above). There are plenty of examples of how to use `.css()` at [the jQuery `.css()` doco page](http://api.jquery.com/css).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to mention like

```
$("Body").css('background-color', 'red'),
$("Header").css('background-color', 'green');
```

If you want more css properties at that time you want to mention like

```
 $("Body").css({'background-color': '#ffe', 'border-left': '5px solid #ccc'})
 $("Header").css({'background-color': '#ffe', 'border-left': '5px solid #ccc'})
```

Comment: Are you saying you _can't_ use the object syntax `.css({})` for only one property? (That's not true.)

Comment: @vinothini, will i be able to set the attributes even if this jquerycode will be in _viewstart.cshtml? i dont have a <style>code</style> in this view. need to access the css file which is located in another folder

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to give the jquery css method a json object. You have to create a string -from your json object- first and then pass it to the css method.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) But the `.css()` method certainly _can_ take an object as a single parameter to set one or more CSS attributes - have a look at [the `.css()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties).

Comment: @nnnnnn Im kinda lost but ur comment with json, can i set the css attributes in _viewstart.cshmt or not?

Comment: thanks for posting the link. A haven't noticed, that jquery up to 1.9 can take that.

Comment: @user2043267 According the documentation, if you using jquery 1.9 or newer jquery can do it.

Comment: The `.css({...})` syntax is pretty handy for setting multiple properties at once. It's worked like that since version **1.0**. (What was added in 1.9 was the ability to pass an array of property names to _retrieve_ multiple values at once.)